# Android Widget + Service

Tags: android, service, action, broadcastreceiver

I'm having problems calling a class function from my Widget as the result of a service action.

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, 
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NeoService.class);
        context.startService(intent);

        MyClass mClass = new MyClass(context, appWidgetManager);
        mClass.doUpdate();

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

The call to mClass.doUpdate() above works just fine. But then when I try to do it again in my onReceive it doesn't work and I get a forceclose as soon as the correct action is received:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     if(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK.equals(action))
    {
        mTime.doUpdate();
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "TicK Tock!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

If I comment out the mTime.doUpdate(); and uncomment the Toast it displays the toast just fine as it should.

Edit: The error message I get is as follows:

```
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x40000004 (has extras) } in de.thesmile.android.widget.HelloWidget@48411298
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:905)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at de.thesmile.android.widget.HelloWidget.onReceive(HelloWidget.java:45)
11-18 18:25:00.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2759):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:892)
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "forceclose". Also, please bear in mind that `doUpdate()` and `doDaUpdate()` are not the same method.

Comment: Sorry my bad, they are both named the same, the "Da" doesn't belong there. I am having problems in that I can't get my Galaxy Tab to report itself as "Debug" capable so I can't step through the program to find problems. Have tried all things today to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem results from the BroadcastReceiver lifecycle. The AppWidgetProvider is a BroadcastReceiver and the BroadcastReceiver is considered active only while proceeding the callback method. When the BroadcastReceiver is inactive (so after the callback method return) your process may be killed at any time if the system needs memory.
When the process is killed, your mTime object is killed too, what causes the NullPointerException.

It is nicely explained here: (especially the second "Note:")
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider

and here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#broadlife